# Delete specific file name with the following Regex:

Tags: powershell, automation

Trying to recourse through to delete certain files in a directory. However, seems like all it does is just output nothing and nothing gets deleted. Please see if what I am doing is wrong.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where{$_.Name -Match "^[0-9]{1,6}$"} | Remove-Item
```

And the following file I'm trying to delete matches that:
000001.tif
000002.tif
etc.
I tried to see if it was a spacing issue between the pipes but no go. Now I'm trying to see if it is a permission issue on my PC but it is not.

I was expecting the regex to delete the files in there that match that regex (6 digits, all have numbers). Is there something wrong that I have done to it?

Update: Thanks guys so far for the help but I hit another hiccup more than I thought.

Running the code:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse| Where{$_.BaseName -Match "^[0-9]{1,6}$"} | Remove-Item -whatif
```

In a directory with subfolders is deleting the subfolders AND the file that match it. I only want to delete the file. I tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -File -recurse| Where{$_.BaseName -Match "^[0-9]{1,6}$"} | Remove-Item -whatif
```

But the results of the Whatif come empty. What is the error for this?

Comment: You want `.BaseName` there instead of `.Name` :)

Comment: Well, there's nothing in your pattern to match the `.tif` part of the file name, so that makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where{$_.Name -like "^[0-9]{1,6}.tif"} | Remove-Item

Answer (score 0):

Here's the wildcard pattern for it.  It works as a path but not a filter.

```
get-childitem -recurse -path [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].tif |
  remove-item -whatif
```

Or

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | where basename -match '^[0-9]{1,6}$' |
  Remove-Item -whatif
```

Comment: Is there any chance that it only get files from subdirectories as well? I updated the question since it seems as though the answer for this had also included the subdirectories. Initially I didn't think of that until now.

Comment: @jsa56 `get-childitem -file`